# why is my solr engine only pulling 10 rows

Tags: solr

I am learning SOLR for the first time.  I am using SOLR 7.2.1 plus java 8.  I am currently following this page:

http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2013/04/29/loading-data-from-sql-server-to-solr-with-a-data-import-handler/

my query is "select * from mytable" with a million records on it.
But when I activate the full load (http://localhost:8983/solr/#/offrs/dataimport//dataimport) only ten records come into the core.

This is what I built:

data.import.xml:

```
<dataConfig>  
    <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource"
            driver="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
            url="jdbc:sqlserver://<<SERVER>>;databaseName=<<DATABASE>>;"
            user="<<USER>>"
            password="<<PASSWORD"
    /> 

    <document name="MY_DOCUMENT">  
        <entity name="doc" query="SELECT * FROM MYTABLE">  
            <field column='Field1' name='field1' />
            <field column='field2' name='field2' />
            ...
        </entity
    </document>
<dataConfig>
```

Schema.XML

```
<schema name='doc' version='1.1'>
    <types>
        <fieldtype name='string' class='solr.StrField' />
        <fieldtype name='long' class='solr.LongPointField' />
        <fieldtype name='integer' class='solr.IntPointField' />
        <fieldtype name='float' class='solr.FloatPointField' />
    </types>

    <fields>
        <field name='field1' type='string' />
        <field name='field2' type='string' />
        <field name='field3' type='string' />
    </fields>

    <uniqueKey>field1</uniqueKey>

</schema>
```

Solrconfig.xml

```
<config>
    <luceneMatchVersion>6.0</luceneMatchVersion>
    <requestHandler name='standard' class='solr.StandardRequestHandler' default='true' />

    <admin>
        <defaultQuery>*:*</defaultQuery>
    </admin>

    <requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">     

    <lst name="defaults">    
        <str name="config">data.import.xml</str>  
    </lst>    
</requestHandler>  
</config>
```

Is there another setting I am needing?

Update #1:
When looking at the SQL Server Activity Monitor, I see the query coming form SOLR....however, it is saying suspended with this error: ASYNC_NETWORK_IO.  I don't know if this helps, but I'm putting in as much data as I can.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide more information around how you are verifying how many documents there are in your Solr environment? If you are trying to just execute the /select or /query endpoints - by default they only return top 10.

Comment: ok.  how can I tell.  as far as I know, I have one document with a million records.  based on data.import.xml

Comment: Hi, I am having the same problem with SOLR. Did you manage to fix it?

Comment: I moved over to elastic search.  Sorry